# The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable error in android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, subdirectory

I'm getting belew error while testing my ecommerce app.

```
:app:processDebugResource
    Execute taskAction$gradle
```

> ```
> Error:- D:\ZEALW2\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\com\google\firebase\iid: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
> ```

[Error screen shoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtNdV.png)

ive tried to delete crrupted folder also, however can't delete the folder.

Pease help me to resolve it.

Comment: try the following in android studio, file -> invalidate cache and restart

Comment: I did it, but same problum is there, its not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late but this is what helped me fix the problem. Run CMD as admin, type `chkdsk /f D:` and press enter. `D:` (D) is your disk/drive name, change it respectively.